# Is there any way reduce Query array which comes from SwiftData to single property?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-data

I have two classes one shows cities, other shows concerts with many to many relationships.
On concert view I have @Query var cities : [City] to select city name from picker.
I'm trying to fetch selected city from @Query var cities : [City]
how to filter the selection city in create button? I tried reduce method but didn't work as well.

```
Picker("Select city", selection: $selectedCity) {
    ForEach(cities) { city in
        Text(city.name).tag(city.name)
    }
}

DatePicker(selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: .date) {
    Text("Concert Date")
}

 Button("Create") {  }
```

Comment: `cities` can be used as any array property so you can use filter or firstIndex(of:) for instance

Comment: You should maintain a boolean eg. isSelected in City model and then you can filter out in create button.